# Run docker containers in interactive mode

Tags: docker

Im trying to run the docker command using the below command but it does not take me to the interactive mode.

```
docker container run -d  -it --privileged centos
```

Comment: Try  without -d option

Comment: If you look at the `docker run` man page, you'll note that `-d` means `--detach` ("run the container in the background...")

Answer (score 2):

After starting your container, you can use

```
docker exec -it your_container_name /bin/bash
```

command to connect container's terminal. (assuming container's image includes /bin/bash).

Comment: On Windows with MinTTY it is: `docker exec -it your_container_name bash`